# Cannot Grab Graph Editor Handles Intermittently in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, animation

On my desktop version of After Effects (not Laptop) I can only sometimes grab handles and béziers—clicking and dragging sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. Usually I keep trying until something happens or select other points and go back to the one I wanted to edit.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdygxqvyy58xe3w/AE.mov?dl=0

This issue seems specific to my desktop (iMac with an attached Cinema Display) as it doesn't happen on my Laptop (a Macbook Pro). The After Effects file is the same file between the two platforms.

Comment: For me it sounds more like a bug, if this doesn't happen on your laptop. Might be better to send a bug report to adobe.

Comment: @poor I did send it along to Adobe as a bug too but I'm not expecting much in return. Thought I'd post it here in hope of finding someone else who has come across this.

Comment: Of course, but it's always good to send a bug report :) good luck!